# Resistor to limit maximum voltage of solar panels

Tags: resistors, solar-energy

I have two 20W solar panels (each Voc = 22.3, Isc = 1.22) in series connected directly to an axial fan driven by an EC motor (rated voltage 48V). Here the maximum operating voltage when very sunny has been about 43 V.

This configuration has worked well in the past but I need a bit more airflow. I want to add in series another panel, this one is a 10W, same voltage, about half the current.

I have read elsewhere that this not need to be a problem for the panels since the operating current will fall to that of the smallest panel. That is fine to me, at the moment I am not aiming for high efficiency. What worries me is that the EC motor might get too much voltage out of the three panels.

From the panel curves it appears that with full sun (around 1000 W/m2) the motor might get 60-62 V.

The operating voltage range of the fan according to its data sheet is 28-56 V. The rated current is 0.5 A, however when I connected the fan to 56V I measured 0.4 A.

## Question

Can I connect a power resistor in series in the circuit so that with full sun the motor "sees" about 56V instead of 60-62V? Is there a way to calculate the required resistance?

Unfortunately for me the fan does not have much information on its properties to help with this.

Comment: What type of fan are you using ….link to a datasheet if possible

Comment: It would be this link to a pdf file:

https://www.luefter.de/files/luefter-technik/fan_search/datasheets/m-fan-datasheet-DA020060.pdf

Comment: The basic thinking here is sound, despite the criticism. It may not be the most efficient way to go, but you can probably make something work. You may have to experiment a bit, though. You can de-power the panels by tilting them away from the sun, then slowly tilt them toward the sun while watching the voltage and current in the motor. If it is too much, you may have to add a resistor. What value? It is hard to estimate. You have to have the V-I curves for the panels, know the irradiance, know the temperature of the panels, the V-I  curve for the fan in your setup, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can't connect unmatched panels in series. Why? Because power will be dissipated in the unmatched module. If three modules are connected in series, they need to be the same.

Secondly, if you don't have an MPPT tracker, your not using the full power of the modules. An MPPT tracker will most likely solve your problems. Why? Because the motor may not be drawing the right amount of current from the modules and if the right amount of current is not drawn, the power capability goes down.

Thirdly, V=I*R is the best way to size resistors.

Comment: I have read in several sites that connecting different panels in series results in added voltage and the current is that of the panel with smallest current.  Yes, that means I am not using the full capacity of the panels but I am fine with that for the moment. I could use 3x10W panels and get the same, but I have 2x20W and 1x10W available , so if this connection does not destroy the panels I am happy with wasting power for now. Or will they get destroyed?
I understand there are more sophiscated ways to handle this (like mppt) but I wanted to know how to do it using a resistor.

Comment: I also know V=IxR but when there is a motor in the circuit  does not that complicate things because of the back emf? We have a supply voltage and the back emf (which is unknown to me as well as the parameters to calculate it). I understand that the resistance of the motor is very low (unknown at the moment). So, if I want to "take away" a few V from the fan (say from 62 to 56 at full sun), does the resistor has to be a fraction of the motor resistance? Like much less than an ohm?

Comment: @FranzRoman They could be destroyed, there is no way to know without knowing the construction of the modules and the limits of the cells. It's easier to match modules so that's what people do. If you want to drop the voltage 3V and your drawing 1A, then the resistor you'd need would be 3v/1A=3Ω

Comment: V=I*R is useless because the only part of the system which follows that law is the resistor. The fan motor does not, the solar panels do not, and there are multiple panels with different V-I curves. Much easier to just try it.

Comment: Well the whole setup is useless, without an mppt tracker, theoretically of the cells were sourcing 1 amp at that a given voltage that's how you world go about calculating the drop

Answer (score 1):

Answer: It will work fine.

The motor load won’t exceed the short circuit current of 0.5A for the 10W20V PV which matches the motor rating.   If the voltage tried to increase , it can’t as the small PV cannot create any voltage when shorted by the smaller resistance and thus the 40V from the 20W20V1A

So your 50W panels will be limited to 25W.

If the short circuit current of rather 10W array happens to be 0.6 or higher, **tilting the small panel to reduce capture of energy will regulate the maximum current limiting** by losing efficacy.

Comment: Did you see where the OP said the actual motor current was only 0.4 A at 56V? I am not saying you are wrong. But the OP should proceed with caution when connecting the third panel. Monitor the voltage across the motor and don't let it get too high.

Comment: They usually operate 10% over nominal voltage to max current rating but current is the cause of winding heat so this is specified.

Comment: It looks like a BLDC motor. So there is no guarantee of a simple one-to-one relationship between input current and winding current. The drive circuit and motor winding, in effect, constitute a DC-DC converter. If the motor gets heavily loaded, mechanically, at high voltage, it may overheat. Like I said, all I am suggesting is that the OP go easy at first and keep an eye on things until sure that all is well.

Comment: Anyway, OP should try it like this cautiously and only add a resistor if needed.

Comment: 3 current sources in series will develop a voltage across each defined by motor load curve but limited by the smallest current even if they were 100V panels

Answer (score 0):

A series resistor is a very ineffective way of maximizing or regulating the power to your fan.

First let's consider your [fan](https://www.luefter.de/files/luefter-technik/fan_search/datasheets/m-fan-datasheet-DA020060.pdf): It's 0.5A at 48V ….increase the voltage and the current will go up, decrease the voltage and the current will go down. Total power at recommend 48V is 24W.

You have two Solar cells that can provide about 40W at 22V which is more than enough power to run the fan. All you really need to do is get the voltage up to the 48V the fan needs.

There are an almost endless supply of DC-DC Boost convertors available from Ebay and the like (here's an [example](https://www.ebay.com/itm/10A-160W-8-40V-step-up-12-60V-Adjustable-DC-Converter-12v-24v-48v-booster-module-/131684593779)). What you are looking for is a DC-DC boost convertor capable of 24 - 48V conversion.
The one I pointed to has the following characteristics:

Input voltage :8-40V ( please don't exceed 40V)
Output voltage :12-60V (continuously adjustable)
Output current :0-10A (Max.)
Output power: 90W, 160W (enhance heat dissipation)
Operating frequency: 150KHz
Conversion efficiency: up to 95%
Operating temperature: -40 to +85 °C

You would be operating it at very conservative loads so should have no problems at all. You'd be able to parallel just two of your panels (they would need diode isolation) and set the output voltage to 48V to suit your fan. The output voltage would be regulated providing there is enough sunlight to meet the minimum of 24W at roughly 20V or so from the panels.

You system would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foVGwI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>